# I have a activity with theme Dialog,but in an activitygroup class it is not visible

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, themes

My problem is similar to this one:
[Android: Dialog themed activity not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963976/android-dialog-themed-activity-not-visible)

but I haven't seen anyone answer it.

here is my code:

```
    public class QueryAct extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener ,          OnItemClickListener , OnResponseListener , OnStartListener
{
    oncreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAct = this ;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_query) ;
        views = new QueryActViews(mAct) ; 
        searchThread = new SearchThread() ;
        searchThread.responseListener = this ;
        searchThread.startListener = this ;
        intialViews(views) ;

        HUtil.checkAppUpdate(this);
    }
}
```

and here is the method in class HUtil

```
public static void checkAppUpdate(Context ctx)
    {
    SharedPreferences sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences(GContst.SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean not_alarm_update = sp.getBoolean(GContst.NOT_ALARM_UPDATE, false);

        if(!not_alarm_update)
        {
            String update_url = sp.getString(GContst.UPDATE_URL, "");
            if(!"".equals(update_url))
            {
                ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx,UpdateDialog.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my manifest.xml. I just set the activity updateDialog's theme like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".UpdateDialog"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```